# Angular.JS service not working

Tags: angularjs

I stuck on this for quite some time. My service didn't work as in it didn't get data from my expected. But it working fine if I put the `$http` request in my controller.

```
    (function(){

    function controlProvider($http) {
        this.getStatus = function (callback){
            $http.get("http://localhost:8080/getStatus")
                .success(function (data) {
                    callback(data);
                }); 
        }; 

    }
    controlApp.service('controlProvider', controlProvider);


    function controlController ($scope,controlProvider){
        controlProvider.getStatus = (function (product) {

                $scope.product = product; 
         });  
    }
    controlApp.controller("controlController", controlController);

    })();
```

Any help advise will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The way you make you callback is breaking angular. You should call in you controller your service, not give to the service the function

Comment: Hi ssbb, thx for your comment, the service part is working fine. I just changed my code to the answer below and everything work fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//maybe like this ?
controlProvider.getStatus(function(product) {
    $scope.product = product; 
})
```

Comment: Great Thx!!!  It work, can you also try to explain why my previous code is not working?

Comment: @LeongSzeKim You are put a new function assigned the controlProvider.getStatus no call. like `contrilProvider.getStatus = function(product) {...};`